# Реально ли сделать бот для браузера на андроид?

Tags: java, android, selenium, бот, flutter

Я написал при помощью selenium webdriver на java программу которая:

1. Открывает браузер, заходит на сайт
2. Взаимодействует с элементами на сайте(нажимает на кнопки и пишет).

Как такое сделать на андроиде (типо поставить webview или открыть сам установленный chrome) в виде приложения, без подключения к компьютеру, а в виде приложения которое просто устанавливаешь.

желательно используя flutter.

Comment: Точно также, как и делаете тут, подключите либу [selendroid](http://selendroid.io/) и точно также будет работать и на телефоне. Если полноценный бот нужен, нужно заморачиваться с профилями и куками.

Comment: @And на appium без подключения к пк тоже можно ?